# Not found error when running a script with `sh`

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a simple shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

var="foo"
echo $var
```

When I run it, using `sh shell.sh` (`shell` being its filename, I get the following error:

```
: not found: 2: shell.sh:
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Is the search path correct? Beacuse just entering the filename wont work. You nees the full path from your homefolder or from the root folder.

Comment: the directory my terminal is in is where the sh file is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `sh ./shell.sh` instead of `sh shell.sh` ?
(for security reasons, the current directory `.` is NEVER in the PATH varable)

Also the first line in your script `#!/bin/bash` is only needed if the script is run by itself,
like `./shell.sh`  (don't forget to do `chmod a+x shell.sh` in that case)

Finally the `sh` command invokes the dash shell, not the bash shell, so it would be wise to invoke bash scripts like  `bash ./shell.sh` instead of `sh ./shell.sh`

Take care with line endings:
Bash does not accept \r\n (CRLF) as line endings (which is windows style).
Only \n (LF) is permitted.

Comment: using bash invokes further errors, "./shell.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found"

Comment: Dear James, don't edit Linux files under Windows. Windows' line endings (CRLF) are not compatible with the rest of the world (LF). The error you see is that you are running a windows formatted textfile under Linux and indeed CR is not a bash command.

Comment: @thom You should this last comment as answer.

Comment: i had a major feeling that would be my problem, but i was hoping notepad++ would handle it.

Comment: No worries :-)  If you are used to notepad++ just switch over to geany (which is native linux). It has the same engine and works almost the same...you'll love it :-)